# C# Method Overloading - Parameter type overloads with derived types

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overloading, constructor-overloading

What are the rules by which C# determines which overload of a constructor (or method) is to be used under the following circumstances:

- Overloads differ only by the type of the parameter
- The overloads are all part of the same type hierarchy

Consider the following:

- A custom type derived from List (only a partial representation here; let's say for the sake of the exercise that the class adds some notion of metadata to List):

  ```
  public class CustomList<Type> : List<Type>
  {
      public CustomList() : base() { }

      [...]

  }
  ```
- A class with different constructors taking different levels of the class hierarchy:

  ```
  public class SomeClass
  {
      public SomeClass(IEnumerable<object> ienumerable) { }

      public SomeClass(IList<object> list) { }

      public SomeClass(CustomList<object> customList) { }
  }
  ```

Which constructor will be called in the following code, and how are the overloads resolved?:

```
CustomList<object> customList = new CustomList<object>();

List<object> list = new List<object>();

IEnumerable<object> enumerable = new object[1];
IEnumerable<object> customListWrappedInEnumerable = new CustomList<object>();

SomeClass customListBuilt = new SomeClass(customList);

SomeClass listBuilt = new SomeClass(list);

SomeClass enumerableBuilt = new SomeClass(enumerable);
SomeClass wrappedCustomListBuilt = new SomeClass(customListWrappedInEnumerable);
```

As a secondary question, are the overloading rules the same for constructors as for other instance methods? If I have this class:

```
public static class DoSomethingClass
{
    public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<object> ienumerable) { }

    public void DoSomething(IList<object> list) { }

    public void DoSomething(CustomList<object> customList) { }
}
```

And I call

```
DoSomethingClass.DoSomething(list);
DoSomethingClass.DoSomething(customList);
DoSomethingClass.DoSomething(enumerable);
DoSomethingClass.DoSomething(customListWrappedInEnumerable);
```

is the behavior the same or different than the constructor? And further, if DoSomethingClass were an instance type instead, would

```
DoSomethingClass do = new DoSomethingClass();
do.DoSomething(customListWrappedInEnumerable);
[...]
```

be any different?

My observation so far has been that the type of the reference passed to the constructor/method entirely determines which constructor is chosen. i.e. the CustomList wrapped in an IEnumerable overloads to the IEnumerable constructor. Would I be correct in assuming that is always the case, or are their exceptions?

Comment: Basically, the overloads are resolved as per the spec. Currently your question would take a *lot* of text to explain the overload resolution of each of the multiple questions you've asked here. Could you read the relevant bit of the spec, and then ask about one specific example which doesn't behave as you explain it to?

Comment: @JonSkeet The question took a _lot_ of text and time to write, too. Suffice it to say that I would obviously not have spent the effort to write this up if I could read the spec and easily find a satisfactory answer, or if there were a specific instance of unexpected behavior I could simply report.

In fact, even looking past MSDN into the C# language spec doesn't help. Every single example given by Microsoft of method overloading where the only difference is the type of a formal parameter specifically does not include examples where the different types are part of the same inheritance tree.